# Probability of losing lotteries needed

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, markov-chains, markov-process

A person earns $x_i$ amount of money every month where $x_i$ is an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda_1$. The amount $x_i(1-p)y$, here $0 \leq p\leq 1$ and $y$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda_2$, is invested every month in lottery $L_1$ while amount $x_ip$ is saved every month. As soon the saved amount becomes at least $Q$ then in that month $Q\cdot z$  is invested in lottery $L_2$ and no money is invested in lottery $L_1$. Here $z$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda_3$.

The person wins the lottery $L_1$ if $x_i(1-p)y>J$ and he wins lottery $L_2$ if $Qz>K$ in any month. All the $J, K, Q$ are constants. The person keeps on investing the money in the above fashion irrespective of winning or losing either of the lottery. I need to find the probability that the person does not win lottery $L_1$. I also need to find the probability that the person does not win lottery $L_2$.

To this end I have formulated the probabilities 
\begin{align*}
Pr(\text{person lose }L_1)
&=
Pr(x_i(1-p)y<J\mid \text{no investment is made in } L_2)
\\
&\phantom{=~}
\cdot   Pr(\text{no investment is made in }L_2)+Pr(\text{investment is made in } L_2)
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
Pr(\text{person lose } L_2) 
&=
Pr(\text{no investment is made in } L_2)
\\
&\phantom{=~}
+Pr(Qz<K \mid \text{investment is made in } L_2) Pr(\text{investment is made in } L_2).
\end{align*}

I want to know if these are right expressions or not. If they are right then is there a way to find $Pr(\text{investment is  made  in } L_2)$? I will be very thankful for any help in this regard. I will appreciate if somebody could point me to a reference where I can find a similar problem.

I assumed that the result of both lotteries are not independent because the investment in lottery $L_1$ depends on the investment in $L_2$. In particular if investment is made in $L_2$ in any particular month then in that month no investment is made in $L_1$.

Another form of $Pr(\text{person lose } L_2)$:

After some brain storming I have some reasoning to solve the $Pr(\text{person lose } L_2)$. As it can be observed the money saved for lottery $L_2$ is a chain process. Hence, if we could find some steady state distribution for the amount of money left after every time  the person invest in $L_2$ then we can write the    $Pr(\text{person lose } L_2)$ as follows 
\begin{align*} 
Pr(\text{person lose } L_2)=\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}Pr(Qz<K|\text{investment is made after p months})Pr(\text{investment is made after p months})
\end{align*}
However this gives the answer
\begin{align*}
Pr(\text{person lose } L_2)=Pr(Qz<K)
\end{align*}
I am not sure this reasoning is right or wrong. any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why you denote constants by capital letters and random variables as lower case?

Comment: @Therkel I have added it explicitly.

Comment: @joriki your point is very valid. Actually in my system the investment is made with the help of an agent. The agent gets money $x_i(1-p)$ from the person then he multiplies it with $y$. Similar is the situation with investment in lottery $L_2.$ I hope this makes sense. I did not include the agent in OP to simplify the question.

Comment: @joriki yes the agent invest their own money for such cases. Seems unrealistic but in this post I assume this situation.

Comment: @joriki i changed it from "From this amount" to "The amount"

Comment: OK, I removed my comments to reduce the clutter.

Comment: @joriki any comment on the expressions that I showed for $Pr(person lose L_1)$ and $P(person lose L_2)$? do you think they are correct or otherwise?

Comment: @joriki I have added another representation for the $Pr(\text{person lose} L_2)$ in my question